# Move the Google Map to searched locations Google places Javascript API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a `Google map` , which is displayed by the following code

```
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 15,
    center: { lat: 37.7577, lng: -122.4376 }
  });
```

As you can see the values are given static for `lat / lng` . But once a location is entered I search `Yelp API` for the places . Which in return gives me locations (along with `lat/lng`) and i pinned them successfully on the map by the following code

```
    results  = data['yelp_places_latlnghash'];

    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

        var markerLetter = String.fromCharCode('A'.charCodeAt(0) + i);
        var markerIcon = MARKER_PATH + markerLetter + '.png';

        marker[i] =  new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            icon: markerIcon,
            title: results[i].name,
            position: { lat: results[i].latitude , lng: results[i].longitude }
          });

            marker[i].placeResult = results[i];
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker[i], 'click',  showInfoWindow_yelp);

    addResult(results[i], i);


        }
```

All pins are shown successfully . but the problem is that `map` does not moves to newly pinned locations , and we've to manually do it .  (I know that dragging functionality of map is built in `google maps API` , but i wanna inform you that I've customized functionality and now i want `map` to bound all searched locations . Any help will be appreciated

Comment: @geocodezip I told that i'd customized the map functioning totally and now stuck .I agree with you that the above questions are asked for the same functionality and i knew these mentioned functions also . but in case these are not working ,neither an error displays

Comment: I tried and your second link . helped thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add option `center : { lat: results[i].latitude , lng: results[i].longitude }` in your marker. Or you can set center after you created marker. The methods set center is "`map.setCenter({ lat: results[i].latitude , lng: results[i].longitude })`"